# Send a value in ajax

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax

So i have a button that gives me an id and i want to send that id via ajax in order to look in the database for the table with the given id, this is my controller

```
  $("#resp").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("name");
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '../readForm',
    success: function(data) {
    }        
     })    
    })
```

and this is the model,

```
    function readForm(id) {
    var query = ("`select * from Questao where id_formulario ="+id+"'");
    console.log(query);

    global.connect.con.query(query, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");

    });

   }
```

So what i want to do is send the id on the controller over to the model so i can do a query with it and look for the correct table, is there anyway i can send the id within the ajax?

Comment: Do you want to send the name of the button?  Can you post the html as well?

Comment: " is there anyway i can send the id within the ajax"...yes, specify the option `data` in your ajax request and set the value to whatever it should be, and then your server can read it from the request. Just like when you post a form back. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ documents it (from the client-side perspective) and also has some examples further down the page.

Comment: `var query = ("\`select * from Questao where id_formulario ="+id+"'");` That's definitely a wrong syntax... Wanna try checking it again?

Comment: the query was for demonstrative purposes but it think it works, at least when i run it on mysql workbench it works, the name of the button is an id that is obtained in another function. @ADyson you mean like "data:id" bellow "url: '../readForm'" ?

Comment: @JoãoMiguel yes exactly, e.g. `data: "1"` for a fixed value, or `data: someVariable` to take it from a variable. This will work both for GET and POST requests. If you want to make sure the value has a specific name when sent to the server, which might be sensible, then `data: { "id": someVariable }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the ID to the ajax call, append it to the end of the URL:

```
$("#resp").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("name");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../readForm?id='+id, // add the ID to the url querystring.
        success: function(data) {
        }        
     })    
})
```